# styles over riding styles when using @media in css

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I am having a noob issue, one that is annoying me greatly. So I have the following type of style sheet:

```
#content .post-content .row .col-md-6 .box-top {
  background: #714f46;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "custom-script";
  position: relative;
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 34px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {

}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  #content .post-content .row .col-md-6 .box-top {
    width: 453px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  #content .post-content .row .col-md-6 .box-top {
    width: 353px;
  }
}
```

Now the issue is that anything over `641px` will use the `640px` rule. Even if the screen is `1920x1200`. I think its because I don't have a width defined for the original element? if thats case, I slap a width on the original element of `453px`:

```
#content .post-content .row .col-md-6 .box-top {
  ...
  width: 453px;
}
```

But the problem is, its almost like the `@media` rule has precedence, because in the crhome inspector when the width is `1366px`, it still uses the `640px` rule instead of the width I just defined. Now I was thinking of, instead of doing: `(min-width: xyzpx)` I would use `max-width` but that seems to take a way the smooth scaling down affect that the client wants, they don't want it jumping between media sizes.

Should my element have a `max-width` of `453px` to override the `@media` rule?

```
#content .post-content .row .col-md-6 .box-top {
  ...
  max-width: 453px; /** or a min-width: 453px **/
}
```

Essentially my questions are:

**Why is my @media rule overriding any other rule on the page. In this case why is it using the width in the 640 rule to apply to anything above when the original definition of the element in question does not specific a width?**

And

**Why is when I specify a width for that original definition of the element, that the @media rule, which defined a new width at 640px overrides it, especially when the windows width is say 1366px?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand your issue is that you want to apply the **Non-Mobile First Method**, and by using that you have to use the **`max-width`** instead of **`min-width`**

like this:

```css
/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    @media only screen and (max-width : 960px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }       
    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/ 
    }
```

or if you want to use the **Mobile First Method** then you should use **`min-width`** but this way:

```css
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 640px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }       
    @media only screen and (min-width : 960px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/ 
    }
```

Below is a snippet from what I understand it is what you are looking for:

```css
#content .post-content .row .col-md-6 .box-top {
  background: #714f46;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "custom-script,arial";
  position: relative;
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 34px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  /*your CSS Rules*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /*your CSS Rules*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #content .post-content .row .col-md-6 .box-top {
    width: 453px;
  }
  /*your CSS Rules*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /*your CSS Rules*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  /*your CSS Rules*/
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="post-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box-top">Something
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using your mobile first method, place a style rule in 480 and then in 640, for me regardless of screen size 480 is always used. Can you explain why this would be?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and tell what is wrong and you want to try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing order of your media queries. Smallest `min-width` first.

Say your window width is 700px. Then `(min-width: 960px)` and `(min-width: 768px)` does not match and are skipped but *both* `(min-width: 640px)` and `(min-width: 480px)` do match styles inside these blocks are applied in order they appear in CSS file. And later styles override previous styles, e.g.:

```
p { color: green; }
p { color: red; }
```

Your `p` color would be red.

This live example may be a bit clearer: http://jsbin.com/yuqigedudi/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    /* Default color when no media queries bellow match.
    In this our case when window width < 200px */
    p { color: black }

    /* If window size >= 200px */
    @media (min-width: 200px) {
      p { color: red }
    }

    /* If window size >= 300px */
    @media (min-width: 300px) {
      p { color: orange }
    }

    /* If window size >= 400px */
    @media (min-width: 400px) {
      p { color: blue }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    Resize this frame and see my color change!
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide any explanation as to why that would affect anything? Also that doesn't do anything at all ...

Comment: switching the media like you show with css in your updated post does not work either. I placed all styles that do not fall into a media query below all the media query rules (css is top down reader), the issue is still the same. if I define something in @media of 480px it sticks for 481+ instead of being over written.

Comment: this still doesn't work for me, your example down, but my thing doesn't. thanks though